# how do I write my code using dictionary comprehension?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I re-write the last three lines of my code using dictionary comprehension?

- If the day_of_week value already exists as a key in the dictionary, add the births value to the existing, associated value.
- If the day_of_week value doesn't exist as a key, add it to the dictionary and set the associated value to the births value for that line.

The column names for the split2 list is as below.

> '**year,  month,  date_of_month,  day_of_week,  births**'

```
 split2 = [['1994', '1', '2', '7', '7772'],
 ['1994', '1', '3', '1', '10142'],
 ['1994', '1', '4', '2', '11248'],
 ['1994', '1', '5', '3', '11053'],
 ['1994', '1', '6', '4', '11406'],
 ['1994', '1', '7', '5', '11251'],
 ['1994', '1', '8', '6', '8653'],
 ['1994', '1', '9', '7', '7910'],
 ['1994', '1', '10', '1', '10498'],
 ['1994', '1', '11', '2', '11706'],
 ['1994', '1', '12', '3', '11567'],
 ['1994', '1', '13', '4', '11212'],
 ['1994', '1', '14', '5', '11570'],
 ['1994', '1', '15', '6', '8660'],
 ['1994', '1', '16', '7', '8123']]


dayofweek = [int(i[3]) for i in split2]
births = [int(i[-1]) for i in split2]
combine = list(zip(dayofweek, births))
edict = {}
for i in combine:
    if i[0] in edict.keys():
        edict[i[0]] += i[-1]
    else:
        edict[i[0]] = i[-1]
print(edict)

output:
{1: 20640, 2: 22954, 3: 22620, 4: 22618, 5: 22821, 6: 17313, 7: 23805}
```

Comment: @RoryDaulton Sorry! I have added more info.

Comment: Glad to be of help. Just updated my answer with more explanations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do:

```
edict = {d: sum(b for w, b in combine if w == d) for d in set(dayofweek)}
```

Since you want your dict to be based every day of week that has appeared in `split2`, or a unique set of them, you can iterate over `set(dayofweek)`, and then for a given day of week, generate the dict key on the day and the value being the sum of births of the day by iterating over `combine` and matching the day and outputting the births of the day with a generator to `sum`.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in combine:
    edict[i[0]] = edict.get(i[0], 0) + i[1]
```

but for a more elegant solution, I would do

```
for i, v in combine:
    edict[i] = edict.get(i, 0) + v
```

this can be done because elements of combine are of type `tuple` and by saying "`i, v`" you automatically unpack it
it is equivalent to saying

```
for i in combine:
    i, v = i
```